# Jquery .submit() function does not get called

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the jQuery code.

```
$('#signinform').live('submit',function() {
    alert("Submitting");
    $("#signinbutton").click();
});
```

The form is like this:

```
<form name="signinform" id="signinform" action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="rounded_login" name="studentid" id="studentid" placeholder="Student ID" required="required" maxlength="9 ">
        <input type="password" class="rounded_login" name="studentpassword" id="studentpassword" placeholder="SJSU One Password" required="required" tooltip="Password">
        <input type="hidden" name="signinmethod" id="signinmethod" value="manual">
        <div id="signinbutton">Sign In</div>
</form>
```

The click event works just fine, but for some reason, the submit doesn't get called. What am I missing?

PS: I've tried with both .live() and .submit() function.

**Edit**: Wow! I guess I did not make myself clear enough! There is already code or submitting the form on click of the button/image.

```
$("#signinbutton").live('click',function (e) {
});
```

What I need to do is, submit it on press of the return key. That isn't happening.
Also, I cannot add a submit input because that would mess the styling.

Comment: You are never submitting your code !

Comment: It must be used on a "submit" element (e.g. button or input with type="submit")

Comment: Also - may I enquire what version of jQuery you're using? .live is depracated now.

Comment: Insert `submit` button and change `live` to `on` function.

Comment: @David, `live` is deleted now... read my answer below. `:)`

Comment: @gdoron Indeed my mistake, I'll edit it to correct. Well - I would it if let me!

Answer (score 3):

If you want your "Sign In" div to trigger the form submission try changing:

```
$('#signinform').live('submit',function() {
    alert("Submitting");
    $("#signinbutton").click();
});
```

to

```
$('#signinbutton').on('click',function() {
    alert("Submitting");
    $("#signinform").submit();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/V7nQs/1/)**

And as gdoron reminded me to note, `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I just can't upvote an answer(or question) with `live`.

Comment: @VaishakSuresh, that thread is a mess, and the edit just makes it worse. I suggest rollback the edit and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
$("#signinform").trigger('submit');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="signinbutton">Sign In</div>
```

This isn't actually a submit button.

You can add an event to this button to make it execute the submit event directly, or make an actual submit button in its place.

Answer (score 0):

You should submit on click and not the other way around.

```
$('#signinbutton').on('click',function() {
    $("#signinform").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your HTML code to the following

```
<form name="signinform" id="signinform" action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="rounded_login" name="studentid" id="studentid" placeholder="Student ID" required="required" maxlength="9 ">
        <input type="password" class="rounded_login" name="studentpassword" id="studentpassword" placeholder="SJSU One Password" required="required" tooltip="Password">
        <input type="hidden" name="signinmethod" id="signinmethod" value="manual">
       <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You are also using `.live()` which is not recommended anymore you should use `.on()`. If you can't change your HTML code you could manually submit the form in your click handler of your div with the id **signinbutton**.

```
$('#signinbutton').on('click',function()){
 $('#signinform').trigger('submit');
}
```

Comment: @AD7six, what was the problem with the markup exactly? is there a rule you can\should submit only with submit button. I wish I could dowvote a comment...

Comment: @gdoron come on. a form with a div in it, and a js handler to submit the form when you click the div instead of a button?

Comment: @gdoron at the end of the day - it is more semantically correct to fix the markup in this situation. A form without a submit button isn't really a good form unless that user is able to benefit from the JS processing it. Without the JS, this form would do nothing (except if they pressed the RETURN key ofcourse). This fixes it's usuability and accessibility.

Comment: @AD7six, You can style div more easily than a button, I believe it's agreed, and if he used a div I believe it should stay a div... it's not "a problem". Yes I would have use a submit button.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to be changed in the markup! The div has a style attached to it to display as button. I don't want to use ugly HTML submit buttons. please see the edit.

Comment: styling a button/input is harder than styling a div? what nonsense is this.

Comment: take your discussion into a chat guys :-D

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with setting events on forms. These could not work, if the form was hidden before.

Answer (score 0):

Put your submit function inside. It should work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#signinbutton").submit();

});
```